# Laravel Forge keeps sending mail through Mandrill after removing from environment file

Tags: php, laravel-5, environment-variables, production-environment, laravel-forge

After Mandrill announced it wasn't going to be free anymore, I started looking for an alternative.  I found Sendgrid which will suit my purposes.

I updated the Environment file with MAIL_USERNAME, MAIL_PASSWORD, and MAIL_HOST information for Sendgrid on Forge.  On my local machine it works and sends through Sendgrid.  On my production, it keeps sending through Mandrill even though the environment file has been updated and Mandrill information deleted.  How is that?  Does Forge use a cache file for the environment that needs to be deleted?

Comment: Forge maintains its own `.env` file, have you double-checked to make sure that one is updated? It certainly wouldn't hurt to restart the Nginx service as well.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that.  The environment file is updated in the "Environment" tab on Forge.

I have a queue worker running, so I restarted it and everything seems to be working now.  I'm wondering if the queue worker had the environment stored in a queue cache or something like that because all mail going through the queue was not working and all mail not going through the queue was being sent to Sendgrid.

Comment: @Robbie  looks like restarting the queue workers fixed the problem for me too.  You should mark that as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was fixed by restarting the queue worker after the environment file was updated.  Confirmed by @retrograde.